# Unnesting nested arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, nested, unnest

Given nested arrays:

```
SELECT ARRAY[ARRAY[1, 2, 3], ARRAY[4, 5, 6], ARRAY[7, 8, 9]];
-------------------------------------------------------------
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

**How would one split the array into rows?**

```
{1,2,3}
{4,5,6}
{7,8,9}
```

I've tried `unnest`, but it applies to the inner elements:

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY[ARRAY[1, 2, 3], ARRAY[4, 5, 6], ARRAY[7, 8, 9]]);
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Unnest_multidimensional_array

Comment: See the function `scan_rows(int[])` in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY).

Comment: I take it this means there is no default function to do this, and you have to resort to PL/pgSQL?

Comment: @bosticko, yes, looks so.